# Deploying vSphere client plugin on vCenter 8.0 is failed

Tags: java, vsphere

vSphere Client plugin Name is appeared on the vCenter with "failed" status with below failure message. I am looking for a solution to resolve this issue.

> "Error deploying plug-in.
> org.osgi.service.subsystem.SubsystemException: Framework could not
> resolve the bundles: [vcplugin-ui_1.2.1 [358],
> vcplugin-controller_1.2.1 [360],
> org.osgi.service.subsystem.region.context.9_1.0.0 [357],
> com.vmware.wsvim25_8.0.0 [359], org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm_1.0.0 [361]]
> org.apache.aries.subsystem.core.internal.StartAction.handleFailedResolution(StartAction.java:643)"

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it's due to the fact that from vSphere 8.0 local plug-ins need changes to support their library isolation.
More about the topic can be read here:

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/vSphere-Client-SDK-Discussions/Failed-to-deploy-a-local-plugin-on-vSphere-8-0/td-p/2932206

Local plug-ins are also deprecated so migrating to a remote plug-in architecture is something to consider going forward.